# changes made to the react file are not getting reflected in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, restart, canvas-lms

i have a file `javascripts/jsx/dashboard_card/DashboardCard.js` in my `rails app` ([canvas-lms](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms)), and the `code` is present below.

`code` :

```
      //React.createElement(
       // 'button',
        //{
          //'aria-expanded': this.state.editing,
          //'aria-controls': this.colorPickerID(),
         // className: 'Button Button--icon-action-rev ic-DashboardCard__header-button ddddddd',
         // onClick: this.settingsClick,
          //ref: 'settingsToggle' },
        //React.createElement('i', { className: 'icon-compose icon-Line ccccccc xxxxxxxx', 'aria-hidden': 'true','visibility': 'hidden' }),
        //React.createElement(
          //'span',
          //{ className: 'screenreader-only' },
         // I18n.t("Choose a color or course nickname for %{course}", { course: this.state.nicknameInfo.nickname })
        //)
      //)
```

i changed this `code` and even `commented`. but the `changes` which i made in this `file` are not getting `reflected` in my rails application. how to `restart` the `react.js` in rails application? I `restarted` rails server also. but nothing is changing.

Comment: Are you uisng webpack or babel-loader?

Comment: i dont know about those. i am working on react for the first time. when i search for "webpack", "babel-loader" in my entire App, both(webpack,babel-loader) are present in my system